# Angular directive on parent to change class of a child element?

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and learning as I go here, so I have not ventured into custom directives. I Have a component that I need to be able to pass a directive into the parent element `<app-date-range></app-date-range>` and pass a class to the child element within the component so that I can alter the `btn-primary-bottom` with `btn-white-bottom` from `<app-date-range></app-date-range>`

```
<button class="btn btn-primary-bottom"
    ngbDropdownToggle>
        {{ startDate | date }} - {{ endDate | date }}
</button>
```

here is the full component template for reference:

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block mr-2" #dateRange="ngbDropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary-bottom"
        ngbDropdownToggle>
            {{ startDate | date }} - {{ endDate | date }}
    </button>
    <div ngbDropdownMenu  autoClose="outside">
        <button class="dropdown-item"
            (click)="dateSelectedFunction('year'); dateRange.close();">
                This Year
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <button class="dropdown-item"
            (click)="dateSelectedFunction('today'); dateRange.close();">
                Today
        </button>
        <button class="dropdown-item"
            (click)="dateSelectedFunction('yesterday'); dateRange.close();">
                Yesterday
        </button>
        <button class="dropdown-item"
            (click)="dateSelectedFunction('seven'); dateRange.close();">
                Last 7 days
        </button>
        <button class="dropdown-item"
            (click)="dateSelectedFunction('thirty'); dateRange.close();">
                Last 30 days
        </button>
        <button class="dropdown-item"
            (click)="dateSelectedFunction('ninety'); dateRange.close();">
                Last 90 days
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <button class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center"
            (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"
            [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed">
                Custom
                <span class="fa fa-chevron-down ml-auto"></span>
            </button>
        <div class="px-4 pb-2"
            [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
                <label><small>Start Date</small></label>
                <input class="form-control form-control-sm"
                    type="date"
                    style="width: 200px;"
                    [(ngModel)]="startDate">
                <label><small>End Date</small></label>
                <input class="form-control form-control-sm"
                    type="date"
                    style="width: 200px;"
                    [(ngModel)]="endDate">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No directive should be needed here. Just an @Input, so that the component tag with input attribute would look something like this:

```
<app-date-range [buttonclass]="'btn-white-bottom'"></app-date-range>
```

Then in the app-date-range component class you need to add a property with an @Input decorator like this:

```
@Input() buttonclass: string;
```

Then finally the button HTML in your component template would be like this:

```
<button class="btn" [ngClass]="buttonclass" ngbDropdownToggle>
    {{ startDate | date }} - {{ endDate | date }}
</button>
```

Comment: Don't forget the inner quotes when you bind a property to a string: `[buttonclass]="'btn-white-bottom'"`.

Comment: Thanks I need to think about using `@Input` and `@Output` more. I forget about it.